# How to correctly profile algorithms to use in audio callbacks?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, profiling

Trying to profile different vectorized convolution algorithms in Unity but it ain't so obvious to do so as results can vary significantly according to how one profiles.

**The environment:**

These are FIR filter convolutions, they are called very often, say at 60FPS by the Unity [OnAudioFilterRead](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnAudioFilterRead.html) callback, and there is about 1024 samples to process.

Basically, called very often and for very short buffers.

**Problem 1:**

Although they're all Burst-compiled to native code and much faster than their managed code counterparts, ironically, profiling them became much harder as all numbers tend to be so low in the profiler that they've become meaningless.

**Problem 2:**

As the built-in profiler isn't up to the task, got hold of the new [Performance Testing Extension for Unity Test Framework](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.test-framework.performance@3.0/manual/index.html) package which already looks much better as you can get a very detailed output.

With [Measure.Method()](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.test-framework.performance@3.0/manual/measure-method.html) you setup a test like this:

```
[Test, Performance]
public void Test()
{
    Measure.Method(() => { ... })
        .WarmupCount(10)
        .MeasurementCount(10)
        .IterationsPerMeasurement(5)
        .GC()
        .SetUp(()=> {/*setup code*/})
        .CleanUp(()=> {/*cleanup code*/})
        .Run();
}
```

But setting up the different numbers above for the test isn't so obvious.

**Question:**

How should I set warmup, measurement and iteration count according my use case?

Comment: The usual mistake people make is to think they should go from a) measuring, to b) finding speedups. The method that *works* is the other way around. First, find the speedups, and then measure. How? Like [*this*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771).